# Arduino GY273 HMC5883L Constant Value

Tags: arduino-nano, magnetometer

I have a GY-273 which has HMC5883L chip (I guess). I am trying to get data. I find a few codes and library (I don't have enough information about HMC5883L) but always all serial port screen there are only one value. 
Here is my sketch:

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>
#include "compass.h"

#define Task_t 10          // Task Time in milli seconds

int dt=0;
unsigned long t;
// Main code -----------------------------------------------------------------
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Serial.print("Setting up I2C ........\n");
  Wire.begin();
  compass_x_offset = -48.23;  //122.17;
  compass_y_offset = 284.69;  //230.08;
  compass_z_offset = 59.87;  //389.85;
  compass_x_gainError = 1.07;  //1.12;
  compass_y_gainError = 1.09;  //1.13;
  compass_z_gainError = 1.01;  //1.03;

  compass_init(2);
  //compass_debug = 1;
  //compass_offset_calibration(3);

}

void loop(){

  t = millis();

  float load;

  compass_scalled_reading();

  Serial.print("x = ");
  Serial.println(compass_x_scalled);
  Serial.print("y = ");
  Serial.println(compass_y_scalled);
  Serial.print("z = ");
  Serial.println(compass_z_scalled);

  compass_heading();
  Serial.print ("Heading angle = ");
  Serial.print (bearing);
  Serial.println(" Degree");

  dt = millis()-t;
  load = (float)dt/(Task_t/100);
  Serial.print ("Load on processor = ");
  Serial.print(load);
  Serial.println("%");


  delay(100);
}
```

And Serial port screen is:

```cpp
Gain updated to  = 1.22 mG/bit
x = -48.23
y = 284.69
z = 59.87
Heading angle = 99.62 Degree
Load on processor = inf%
x = -48.23
y = 284.69
z = 59.87
Heading angle = 99.62 Degree
Load on processor = inf%
x = -48.23
y = 284.69
z = 59.87
Heading angle = 99.62 Degree
Load on processor = inf%
x = -48.23
y = 284.69
z = 59.87
```

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqE0TB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @LookAlterno This value is always the same. No change.

Comment: Are you asking for someone to debug your code?

Comment: @LookAlterno Actually I didn't understand what is the problem. It is my first test. I'm not sure problem is code or module (or as I have just learned, continuous mode etc.). I'm asking what the problem is.

Comment: Those values are written in the setup function to the variables. You never get anything from the sensor. Run the i2c scanner to find the i2c address https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2cScanner . There are also clone sensors (QMC5883). What is "compass.h" ? Is that a library ? Did you write "compass.h" yourself ? The Arduino Nano runs at 5V, but the HMC5883L is a 3.3V sensor. It can get damaged when you connect sda and scl to the Arduino Nano without i2c level shifter.

Comment: @Jot Yes, compass.h is a library which is I find on the net. I have tried i2cscanner. It said `I2C device found at address 0x0D`. GY-271 3.3V but GY-273 3.3-5V as I saw on the net. [compass.h is here](https://github.com/helscream/HMC5883L_Header_Arduino_Auto_calibration)

Comment: I think there are 4k7 pullup resistors on the module from sda to 3.3V and from scl to 3.3V. Therefor you can connect the module to an Arduino Uno without i2c level shifter. The address 0x0D is the QMC5883 (fake HMC5883L). There is a library for it: https://github.com/mechasolution/Mecha_QMC5883L but please don't use it. Get a real HMC5883L. Perhaps if you change the library (the compass_address to 0x0D in compass.cpp) and perhaps some of the fake sensor will work, although I read that the QMC5883 is not compatible with the HMC5883L.

Comment: @Jot I supposed it's HMC5883l. It works with the library which you gived thank you. I have changed the address but it didn't work.